# Configuration for RequireJS to consult node_modules?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, node-modules, umd

i'm authoring some modules for npm in umd format -- they're for node and the browser

i'm using requirejs to load the modules clientside to work on them

but requirejs can't find modules within node_modules -- getting 404's for the module identifiers at the web root

**what configuration do i need to give requirejs so it will consult node_modules by default?**

Comment: i'm happy to use literally any other module loader that can accomplish this task — i've found systemjs was a pain because it requires ".js" extensions which ruins the isomorphic nature of my code working in node (which abolishes extensions in module identifiers)

Comment: i want to avoid a bundling step, otherwise i'll have to create too many bundles for my use-case — if i was in the business of bundling right now, i'd obviously just use `browserify` because it's the best javascript tool ever made

Comment: tldr — i just want a module loader that works as easily as browserify, sans the bundling